# Run it under water, hold it under water, run water over it

Tags: word-usage, usage

The following sentences are about rinsing something under running water, be it a whisk (or any utensil for that matter) or a scald, wound/cut.

1. Just **run it under water.**
2. Just **hold it under water.**
3. Just **run water over it.**

Do all of the above sentences sound equally likely?

Comment: I would say 'Hold it under running water' (_under water_ suggests dipping it in still water).

Comment: 'Just run it under water.' and 'Just run water over it.' are perfectly fine aswell.

Comment: I wouldn't use the same expression for a scald and a whisk.  For the latter I would use "rinse".

Comment: As @KateBunting implies, *hold it under water* suggests immersion in a pot of water

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference between 1 and 3, which mean the same thing, and 2.

"Run it under water" and "run water over it" imply you're holding the item under a faucet. "Hold it under water" could mean exactly the same thing, but as a standalone sentence, it sounds more like you're immersing the item in a tub/bowl/sink, not holding it under running water.

I'd prefer 1 or 3, but 2 is fine if the context is made clear.

Answer (score 0):

"Hold it under water" would probably be understood as "hold it underwater", meaning immerse it in a sink or bath or lake or river.

"Hold it under some water" would probably be taken to mean the same as the other two (ie run it under a tap/faucet of running water)